Amoeba population extinction - confusion about the solution
This type of problem has been covered several times, but I do not fully understand the solution.
The text of the problem is the following:
There is an ameba in a pond. After every minute, the amoeba may die, stay the same, split into two or split into three with equal probability. All its offspring, will behave the same. What is the probability the
amoeba population will die out?
To solve the problem, first let $p = Pr(\text{all amoebas die})$ and then condition on all the possible event that can happen after one minute (die, stay the same, etc.). Denote these events $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$. By the law of total probability:
$$
p = \frac{1}{4} \left( Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_1)  + Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_2) + Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_3) + Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_4) \right)
$$
Now, it is clear that $Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_1) = 1$ since the event $E_1$ is that the initial amoeba dies. Moreover, it is also clear to me that $ Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_2) = p$ since given $E_2$ (the amoeba stay the same) we are in the same situation of the beginning, so the probability must be the same.
What I do not understand is why $Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_3) = p^2$ and $Pr(\text{all amoebas die}|E_4) = p^3$.
I understand that the events of multiple amoebas dying are independent. However, isn't $p$ the probability that all amoebas die ? Why does the probability that all amoebas die given we have two amoebas is then equal to $p^2$ ?

$p$ is the probability that the lineage from the original amoeba dies out, and is also the probability that the lineage from any particular amoeba dies out.
After $E_3$ (spilt into two):

All the amoebas (amoebae?) will die out if both lineages from the two amoebas die out.

The lineage from one amoeba will die out with probability $p$, and the lineage from the other amoeba will die out with probability $p$.

These are independent so the probability both lineages die out is their product, i.e. $p^2$.


Something similar happens after $E_4$ but now you need three independent lineages to die out, so with probability $p^3$.

+1 : This is an elegant, clear explanation.

Yes, but maybe what confuses me is the definition of the event "All amoebas die", which by assumption has probability p. For me, this is different from the event "All amoebas die, starting from a single amoeba", and it has a different probability, right? I agree though that by defining the event as "All amoebas die, starting from a single amoeba" the solution makes more sense...

@pdb The question is essentially "There is an amoeba in a pond.... What is the probability the amoeba population will die out?" and if this has probability $p$ then it is the probability "All amoebas die, starting from a single amoeba".

Note: We are implicitly assuming independence of the amoeba lineages.
